# is there a module to manage a simple blog in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, express

I've started few weeks ago to use Node.js, at the moment i'm developing my simple website with node.js + express, but i'm looking for a module to manage a blog(a simple blog, articles+comments).

Could you advice me ?

Thank you

Comment: There is nothing standard out there, but there are various modules out that "make this easier". You might want to look at [substance.io](http://substance.io/) or just write it yourself, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to look at [LooseLeaf](http://looseleafjs.org/) which is a lightweight, no-database, JSON based blog engine or [wheat](https://github.com/creationix/wheat/) which is used by [howtonode](http://howtonode.org/).

Comment: Looseleaf repo hasn't been updated in 2 years, it appears dead.